# Не отображается содержимое в админке. Пишет "У Вас нет административных элементов." drupal 7

Tags: drupal

Мне нужно вывести список элементов из базы данных и показать их в админке. Делаю хук меню

```
function utilitybill_menu() { 
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/structure/utilitybill'] = array(
    'title' => 'Utility bills',
    'description' => 'Utility bill list',
    'page_callback' => 'utilitybill_list',
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
  );
```

Делаю функцию utilitybill_list()

```
function utilitybill_list() {
  $header = array(
    array('data' => t('Title')),
    array('data' => t('URL')),
    array('data' => t('Actions'))
  );
  $docs = db_select('utilitybill_docs', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('id', 'title', '    bg_image_full'))
    ->execute()->fetchAll();
  $row = array();
  if ($docs) {
    foreach ($docs as $item) {
      $actions = array(
        l(t('edit'), 'admin/structure/utilitybill/doc/' . $item->id . '/edit'),
        l(t('delete'), 'admin/structure/utilitybill/doc/' . $item->id . '/delete'),
      );

      $row [] = array(
        array('data' => $item->title),
        array('data' => $item->bg_image_full),
        array('data' => implode(' | ', $actions)),
      );
    }
  }

  return theme('table', array(
    'header' => $header,
    'rows'   => $row,
  ));

}
```

Должна возвращаться таблица с данными. Но вместо этого в админке на странице  "admin/structure/utilitybill" пишется "У Вас нет административных элементов."

Если я эту же функцию делаю как обычную страницу с параметром

```
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
```

То всё нормально. Таблица отображается. А в админке нет. Подскажите, что делать.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка синтаксиса.

```
'page_callback' => 'utilitybill_list',
```

нужно заменить на

```
 'page callback' => 'utilitybill_list',
```